# Bipartite graph that has $|N(A')|\geq |A'|$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$. Show that if $G$ has a matching that covers every vertex of $A$, then for every $A'\subseteq A$, we have $|N(A')|\geq|A'|$, where $N(A')$ denotes the set of neighbours of $A'$.

This sseems pretty obvious but I can't put it into correct words. If $G$ has a matching that covers every vertex of $A$ then the degree of all vertices of $A$ is going to be at least $1$ or else the matching wouldn't contain all vertices of $A$. So the number of neighbours of $A'$ is going to be at least the number of vertices of $A'$.

I don't know how to be rigorous with this. Also if anything that I have said is incorrect in any way, then please say.

Ok here is my new answer: Let $G=(V,E)$. Consider A'. Since we have a matching that covers all vertices of A, then this matching clearly covers all vertices of A'. The degree in each vertex of A' is going to be at least 1 - otherwise there cannot be a matching that covers all vertices in A'. Further, there cannot be any edge that share vertices in A' otherwise G would not be a bipartite graph. So for edge $uv \in E$, either u is in A' and v is in B or vise versa. This means edges that come from vertices in A' is going to be joined to vertices in B. Since we said the deg of each vertex in A' is at least 1, then there is clearly going to be at least |A'| edges that are incident to vertices in A'.

Since we have a matching that covers all vertices in A', and since each vertex degree is at least 1 in A', each vertex is going surely going to have at least $1$ neighbour that is different to the other neighbours that the other vertices in A' have. If it didn't then there would be an edge that shares the same vertex in A' meaning there would be no matching (that covers all vertices of A'). So this means there is at least going to |A'| neighbours in vertices of A' that are different to each other. This means $|N(A')|\geq |A'|$.

Now what do you think of it now? Again please point out ANYTHING that is wrong with it or can be improved or can be justified more.

Comment: A piece of meta advice I'd wish someone had given to me sooner, would be to never ever write down the word *obvious* anywhere near a proof.

Comment: I never used that word anywhere in my answers... when I said 'obvious' that was not part of my answer.

Comment: Peace, I'm not judging or implying it was. It's just that a sure fire way of ticking off my professors would be to call anything obvious regarding proofs. I meant well to caution you about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- The matching gives you a bijection between $A$ and some some subset of $N(A)$. In other words you can point out at least $|A|$ distinct vertices of $N(A)$.
- Matching that covers $A$ covers also any $A'\subseteq A$.

**Solution:**

> Let $M \subseteq E$ be the matching that covers $A$. It also covers $A'$, because $A' \subseteq A$. Let $M' \subseteq M$ be the set of edges of $M$ that are incident to the vertices of $A'$. In particular, $M'$ is also a matching that covers $A'$. No two edges of $M'$ share a vertex, hence vertices in $B' = V(M)\cap B$ are all distinct, so $|B'| = |M'| = |A'|$. Yet, all the vertices of $B'$ share an edge with some vertex of $A'$ (because of $M'$), hence $B' \subseteq N(A')$. Combining that with the previous equality we get $|N(A')| \geq |B'| = |A'|$.$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: So after that hint, can you just simply say the result we are trying to prove is true? Because I cant think of anything else to add to that...

Comment: @snowman That depends on how formal/informal you would like to be. If this would be an _introductory_ course in graph theory or discrete math, then I would not accept it.

Comment: I would want to be as formal as I can. But I can't think of a way to use expressions to say what needs to be said.

Comment: @sandman Try again. For example, the attempt at proof in your post is wrong, because even if the degrees are $\geq 1$, then all these edges could connect to the same vertex. That is impossible if you have a matching, but you didn't used that. As you see "pretty obvious" does not make things automatically correct, try to write a proof with scrutiny that would catch this error in your initial reasoning.

Comment: When you say all those edges could connect to the same vertex, that would mean yes there is no matching but this is never going to be the case cuz we have the assumption that there is a perfect matching...

Comment: @snowman You are correct, but that was not in your proof (as I have already written in the previous comment). The burden of proof is on your side, that is, you have to deal with _all possible cases_, not wait until someone asks "and what if $XYZ$?" To put it in yet another way, it is not my job to point out potential flaws in your reasoning, rigorous proof should not have such unclear steps in the first place.

Comment: Please can you look at the main post now. I made another answer.

Comment: @snowman "[T]here is [~~clearly~~] going to be at least $|A'|$ edges that are incident to vertices in $A'$" is true, but "This means $|N(A′)|≥|A′|$" is false, that is, $|N(A′)|≥|A′|$ does _not_ follow from the first claim.

Comment: There is clearly going to be at least |A'| edges that are incident to vertices in A'. This means that the sum of the degrees for all the vertices of A' is going to be at least |A'| which means |N(A')|>=|A'|? Is that better?

Comment: @snowman No, it is not, you are repeating the very same mistake over and over. The sum of degrees will indeed be at least $|A'|$, but that by itself does not give you $|N(A′)|≥|A′|$. You cannot take _any_ edges, you have to take some particular edges that will ensure that vertices on the other side will be distinct. Degrees do not distingush between the edges, which means that when you start talking about degrees _only_, then you "forget" that you had the matching, which is crucial.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Correct me if I am wrong but I think I have been over counting because I didn't consider each vertex of A' having a similar neighbour. I assumed they all had different neighbours. I have added more to the main post. Please can you have a read of that!!

Comment: @snowman That was a big improvement $\ddot\smile$ There are some minor things you could do better (e.g. you don't have to talk about degrees at all), but it's fine now. I would suggest to leave it as it is and go on with some new problem (you will learn more studying other problems rather than just dwelling on this one). For your convenience I've edited my answer to include a full solution. Please observe that mine is not perfect either, the goal is to be clear _enough_ and don't miss out any of the important details (like the one with overcounting). Congratulations, well done!

Comment: @snowman (And keep that persistence you have!)

Comment: Thanks I will. Quick question, what is V (M)? Vertices of M?

Comment: @snowman Yep, vertices of $M$.